# Express Server routing configuration for Vue App

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to serve my Vue app with an Express server (on production environment). I think there is something wrong (missing?) with my current configuration, since it's not running the App like it should.

This is my configuration:

*simple-tasks-organizer-frontend/package.json*

```
{
   "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start-prod": "node server.js"
  },
}
```

*simple-tasks-organizer-frontend/server.js*

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var express = require('express');

var PORT = 8080;
var app = express();
app.use(history());
app.listen(PORT);
```

*simple-tasks-organizer-frontend/src/router/index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Signin from '@/components/Signin.vue'
import Signup from '@/components/Signup.vue'
import Records from '@/components/tasks/Tasks.vue'
import Automations from '@/components/automations/Automations.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/tasks',
      name: 'Tasks',
      component: Records
    },
    {
      path: '/automations',
      name: 'Automations',
      component: Automations
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Signin',
      component: Signin
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'Signup',
      component: Signup
    }
  ]
})
```

When I enter `http://localhost:8080/` I get the following error message: `Cannot GET /`.

I hope some one of you can help me out with this issue!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you dont have to serve your Vue app with express server.

Vue routing has nothing to do with Express.js routing.

Vue app, once built can be deployed to any static server (apache, nginx, S3, etc.)

If you are looking for all-in-one solution with server-side rendering you shall consider using [nuxt.js](http://nuxtjs.org)

If you still need to server your app with express take a look at [express-serve-static-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-serve-static-core). And keep in mind that express should server your built app version.

Comment: thanks Ivan for you fast response! I'm an absolute newbie in this topic, so maybe you can provide me more info how I can use nginx for the vue app? My backend API is already running on nginx and puma. which steps do I have to make in order to run the Vue app as well on nginx?

Comment: Just set up nginx to serve static, the way you set up serving any other static content (images/html/etc). Build your vue app (npm run build) and place the contents of your output (by default /dist folder) to the place your nginx server files from.

Comment: Great! I'll do it like that! Thanks Ivan!!